# I can't understand the meaning of this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image]

> "First of six total heats- each a little longer and hotter than the last to suck up the oxygen rich environment that scales love so much."

Link: http://m.imgur.com/gallery/w32RT

Above is the sentence I have ever seen in the article in the web.
But I didn't understand the translation of the sentence.
What is the meaning of the sentence above?
Please, tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clearer way to say this sentence:

> This is the first of six heat treatments. Each heating will be a little longer and hotter than the previous one, in order to remove the oxygen which causes mill scales.

Mill scales are a type of rust that forms when you work with steel when too much oxygen is nearby. The rust is weak, and will break off eventually. It doesn't seem to hurt the metal, it's just a nuisance.

Comment: I can not understand the part "scale love so much?"